# Contradicting Git Messages: Merge and Remove

Tags: git, branch, cloud9-ide

Using Cloud9 and having problems because the .c9 folder was added to git.  Trying to remove it.  Git is asking me to remove a file before I can merge to the master branch.  When I try to remove it, git tells me the file doesn't exist.

```
erikvdw@blog:~/workspace (master) $ git merge Post_initial_setup
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .c9/metadata/workspace/.gitignore
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
erikvdw@blog:~/workspace (master) $ git rm .c9/metadata/.gitignore --cache
fatal: pathspec '.c9/metadata/.gitignore' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the entire .c9 folder to be ignored, keeping the .gitignore file within it doesn't make sense. Just update/create the .gitignore file within the workspace/repo root folder with a line added to ignore the `.c9` folder. (Which I assume you've already done since git is saying your .c9/metadata/.gitignore file is untracked).

The error is happening because you've already committed the .c9 folder which had a .gitignore file inside. Now because of the updated global .gitignore file the current `.c9/metadata/.gitignore` is untracked, but previously it was *tracked*. Since you no longer want to keep it around, I think its safe to remove the `.c9/metadata/.gitignore` file, and not just from git (in which it doesn't exist now that its untracked, hence the error), but from the file system, so `rm .c9/metadata/.gitignore`. (Or you may want to move it to another folder outside the git repo). Repeat similar steps for the other files you want to un-track.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR answer: you can't fix this correctly until you decide what "correct" means in this case.

It's not clear to me whether you *want* this `.c9` sub-directory—or more precisely, some or all of its files—to be version-controlled:

> because the .c9 folder was added to git.

("It was added", but not *by* anybody, it just mysteriously appeared! :-) Clearly someone or something added and committed; who and why?)  Meanwhile:

> `.c9/metadata/workspace/.gitignore`

The existence of this file says that you *do* want at least some, but maybe not all,<sup>1</sup> of the files here to be version-controlled.

Typically, if you *do* want that, you *also* want the corresponding `.gitignore` file to be version-controlled as well, i.e., it should be a "tracked file", not an "untracked file".  That way everyone who clones this repository will get the correct `.gitignore` file to avoid version-controlling specific files.

(Keep in mind here that I know nothing about this Cloud9 IDE, so I can't tell whether it's a good or bad idea to version-control stuff in `.c9`.)

If you *do* want some or all of `.c9` tracked and version-controlled, including `.c9/metadata/workspace/.gitignore`, then you simply need to add and commit this file (and perhaps some or all of the other `.c9` files) in your own branch before merging someone else's branch in which they have also added and committed the `.gitignore` file (and perhaps some or all of the other `.c9` files).

If you *don't* want them tracked and version-controlled, you need to:

1. find out why someone else (the other branch) does: was it on purpose, or their mistake?
2. decide on your strategy to deal with that: get them to fix it, or fix it yourself?

and then take actions depending on the result of step (2).

---

<sup>1</sup>The word "maybe" is in here because it's common practice to commit an empty `.gitignore` file in a directory just to force git to create the directory.  An empty `.gitignore` file tells git that, when git goes to complain about untracked files that need to be added, the list of files it should *not* complain about—i.e., should ignore—is empty.

In other words: "please do complain about untracked files, except for this empty list of names" => "please do complain about *all* untracked files".  In this case the existence of `.gitignore` is a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring): it's being used as a dummy empty file just for the side effect of creating the directory.